# original shareholders' interest and SEO

Tags: stocks

I understand that the announcement of a secondary equity offering would often sends stock prices falling. but in light of an announcement like this, would it still be to the original shareholders' best interest to issue new stocks if it was used to raise capital for the funding of a +NPV project in an efficient market?

Comment: In an efficient market, wouldn’t the share price reflect the perceived equity of the company, both before and after dilution?

Comment: yes but I'm asking if it would still be in the original shareholders' interest to issue the stocks now in light of this announcement

Comment: That sounds very detail-specific. I'm not sure it can be definitively answered with a Yes or a No in general. Also, this question sounds very similar to your [other question on the same topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/108067/75926). What is the difference between the two questions?